# Running capybara in a controller to test a few things but can only run it once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, cucumber, capybara

Yes, I know I shouldn't be, but I just need to run a little bit of Capybara script in a controller.

The problem is it opens up an browser and everything, however I want to complete shut down the test or run it in isolation.

So for example if I run something like:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'https://www.google.com'
Capybara.visit("/")
Capybara.has_content?('foo')
Capybara.reset_sessions!
```

The browser and session is still left open.

If I close the browser down and re-run the test it throws an "Connection refused - connect(2)" exception.

I have to re-start the whole rails app to be able to re-run the test.

This there a way to run and re-run several Capybara test over and over again without have to restart anything?

Something hypothetical like this would be good:

```
Capybara.new do
    #the tests...
end
```

or this at the end… `Capybara.shutdown`

I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Comment: Are you running Capybara actually IN the controller?  Why wouldn't you run it in a controller spec instead?

Comment: Well it's actually in a model, I just happen to need a few Capybara commands just for a quick job in an old api-less system.

Comment: So are you running Capybara against your own application? Or some external web server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capybara's selenium driver has a [`quit` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Selenium/Driver#quit-instance_method). When Capybara starts a browser it registers `at_exit` hook that will invoke quit.

But as you want to quit it itself you should do two things:

1. Invoke `Capybara.page.driver.quit` yourself
2. Monkeypatch Capybara so that you won't get errors when Capybara tries to close browser when you have already closed it:

   ```
   # from https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb#L9
   # code inside at_exit hook is removed
   class Capybara::Selenium::Driver
     def browser
       unless @browser
         @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(options[:browser], options.reject { |key,val| SPECIAL_OPTIONS.include?(key) })
       end
       @browser
     end
   end
   ```

Here is a POC code - https://gist.github.com/abotalov/6274926

---

As you need just "a few Capybara commands" you can also write a helper method if you want:

```
def with_capybara(&block)
  Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
  session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
  block.call(session)
  session.driver.browser.quit
end
```

Here is a POC code too - https://gist.github.com/abotalov/6274999

Answer (score -2):

I can't say I understand why you are trying to do this...  However here are a couple of things to try.

From: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

> ### Transactions and database setup
>
> Some Capybara drivers need to run
>    against an actual HTTP server. Capybara takes care of this and starts
>    one for you in the same process as your test, but on another thread.
>    Selenium is one of those drivers, whereas RackTest is not.

Given that, when using Selenium, Capybara needs to start an actual HTTP server, you should try an alternative driver like RackTest.  Capybara may not understand you need the HTTP server shutdown.

Also, from that same section:

> It is also possible to force your ORM to use the same transaction for
>   all threads. This may have thread safety implications and could cause
>   strange failures, so use caution with this approach. It can be
>   implemented in ActiveRecord through the following monkey patch:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

You may try the provided patch to see if Capybara is initiating threads that are not being shutdown, too.

In either case, I have no idea whether these options will help you, but it's something to try.

Comment: Any drive-by that down votes an answer, or a question, without the courtesy of any explanation is just a worthless creeper.